# Can anaerobic digestion of syngas be considered as a primary claim?

Tags: prior-art-request, us20130203144

The Prior Art (e.g. US4289625, 1981) cited by the patent application US20130203144 already discloses the process of feeding a "pyrolysis syngas" to an "anaerobic digester", however the Prior Art covers pyrolysis gases within the scope of products of a thermal gasifier.  Pyrolysis is one reaction within an overall gasification process, therefore gasification products contain pyrolysis syngas.   Yet the application US20130203144 offers an overly broad Claim 1 - a) producing a synthesis gas from pyrolysis of a feedstock; and, b) adding the synthesis gas to an anaerobic digester.

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: Can a new patent restrict the practice of Prior Art by being a more narrow, but necessary, inclusion in the Prior Art?  For example in this case, the Prior Art would be: "washing a shoe in a washing machine", and the Application is "washing the sole of a shoe in a washing machine".  The Prior Art includes washing the sole of the shoe.  If the primary claim of the Application were granted, I am asking if one could no longer practice the Prior Art, because shoes include soles.  So if one were to wash a shoe, one would be washing the sole as well and therefore conflicting with the Application.